# Set a default value for a generic type parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to make a generic function that takes a literal string parameter and returns a value depending on the passed parameter. But this parameter should be optional, and if it was not passed, then I need to set the default value.

```js
type Foobar = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f'

function f1<T extends Foobar = 'a'>(param: T = 'a') {}

function f2<T extends Foobar>(param: T = 'a') {}

function f3<T>(param: T = 'a') {}
```

How do I set a *default value* for the `param` if all the examples above don't work?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that motivates the need for generic type parameters at all (if the return type depends on it, it would be helpful to show it), otherwise you will invite answers that don't meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.  You don't need the generics based on what you're asking.  You already have a type defined that you can use as the parameter type.

`function f3(param: Foobar = 'a') {}`

Comment: As I wrote above, I need to change the return type depending on the passed parameter. For this, I need to use the type parameter. Otherwise, the return type will be a union of all possible types.

Comment: What is the type of the return value?